# .archive-title li a colour issues

Tags: php, css

I have a blog page that includes an archive. 
To display the archive I have used:

```
<div class="archive-title">
   <?php the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );?>
 </div>
```

I have created a sidebar with

```
<div id="sidebar">
   <ul>
      <?php
      if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('blog-sidebar') ) :
      endif; ?>
   </ul>
</div>
```

..and added widgets to display the categories and archive links in the sidebar.

The issue is that on the archive posts page the main background of the posts is white and the sidebar is a dark blue.
I need the colour of the link on the sidebar to be white, but now it just shows an empty bulleted list (because the text is white) above the posts. 
I can not change the colour of the .archive-title li a on the main page without changing it on the sidebar as well. I also can not hide it without hiding it on the sidebar.

You can see the issue here:
http://lumency.co/2019/03/

You will notice blank bullet points with no text above the posts.
How do I change the colour above the posts without affecting the colour on the sidebar as well?
Please let me know if you need any other info. Thanks!

Comment: This is a CSS question, not PHP. I've not seen a `li`s without a parent before. If you have each a parent it would be easier to target. Maybe something like `#sidebar li{
 color: #fff;
}
.post-info li{
 color: #000;
}`

Comment: You could look into adding a new class to the ul surrounding this list and then just use .new-list-class li a {color:new_color}. You could - if you had it... I think you should have a look at your code because your li elements are not wrapped in ul or menu, so technically the code wouldn't validate as is.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpfull to mention that you are using WordPress...

Do you have access to change css? My advice would then be to add a class to the list under the title `.mainlist` and use css like this

```
.mainlist li a { /* change the style of the list under the title*/
    color: black;
}

.sidebar li a { /* change the style of the s*/
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

note: you are putting li tags into a div tag and it's a mistake. because li tags most only be child of a ul tag.

and for change .archive-title li a colors use below code.

```
.archive-title > li > a { color: #666666; }
```

Comment: I’m not completely sure what's your issue

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions! 
I added an

in my sidebar which helped me style it. 
I also removed the  from my archive page, which was what was actually causing all the issues because I had no idea why it was adding a list there making me unable to style it. Haha, ooops!